# Sawstop CNS vibrating / slipping when slowing down

Tags: table-saw

I have a relatively new Sawstop CNS and when it is shut off it vibrates and makes a loud noise. I have tried to capture it in this video i took. Does anyone know if it is normal?

https://youtu.be/QA0M6xzJ0zo

Comment: I'm sure the best advice here would be to contact Sawstop directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have read, this is not all that unusual on contractor saws.  What is happening is that as the motor slows down, it slows at a different rate than the belt, so there is some slippage as the speeds equalize.

[Here](https://forums.woodnet.net/showthread.php?tid=7327906) is a link to a post on Woodnet that describes it in more detail.  As long as it is running fine when under power, there really isn't anything to worry about.